# Update text in place for Mac OS command line app

Tags: swift, macos, command-line

I'm writing a simple mac os (10.11) command line app in Swift to download a file from a valid remote URL and I'd like to show the % of file downloaded in place on the console.

It would start with:

```
0% of 10Mb file downloaded
```

Then when I have some percentage of the file downloaded, the above line would get replaced with:

```
18% of 10Mb file downloaded
```

Finally, when it finishes, the string gets replaced in line with:

```
100% of 10Mb file downloaded
```

`print(..)` will keep append to existing text - is there another function that will do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the cursor at the end of the line (i.e, by not outputting a newline `'\n'` at the end), you can return to the start of the line by outputting a carriage return (`'\r'`). Further output will overwrite what is already on the line.

I'm not super familiar with Swift, but I suspect you may need to explicitly flush output to get a partial line to show up. If you were using standard C I/O, this would be `fflush(stdout)`; I'm not sure what the Swift equivalent is, but I'm sure it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
\u{1B}[1A\u{1B}[k
```

to your string.
for example:

```
print("\u{1B}[1A\u{1B}[kDownloading \(myProgress)%")
```